# Unable to install firebase in expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, npm, expo

I using expo 3.27.10 and node v12.18.4 below is package info I tried to install firebase using expo and npm both fails then how I initialize firebase config file

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
```

and package.json is

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^7.6.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^9.2.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.1",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "firebase": "7.9.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

For me I have to change node version current 14.13 to LTS 12.18 and this allows me to install firebase

Answer (score 2):

If: `expo install firebase`
isn't work for you and you got an Error,

1. That maybe you are having an old **npm version** uou need to update your npm

   `npm update`
2. Or you got error for installation that because **FIREBASE** made update so to fix it use

   `yarn add firebase`

see more: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. What I did:

```
- remove firebase from the package.json.
- npm update
- npm install
- npm install --save firebase
```

afterwards had to change import * as firebase from 'firebase' to

```
import firebase from 'firebase' 

if(firebase.apps.length === 0){
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}
```

p.s: working with VSCode, node v14.15.1, firebase 8.2.7

Answer (score -1):

Downloading 2019 visual studio tools solved the error for me. You can scroll down and download only 2019 tools if you don't Want Visual Studio.

Click the link to download [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: That's completely irrelevant and not shown how to solve the issue since it's related to npm packages.